# How to disable eager execution in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

Seems buggy. A lot of stuff doesn't work. On the other hand tensorflow 2.0 seems to fix a lot of issues with tensorboard interaction so is worth using. How to turn off all eager stuff.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To disable the **eager execution** (and not TF2 behavior in general), do:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

This is a global effect.

Comment: Is it globally turning off the eager mode?

Comment: @GabrielChu Yes, I've edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You can call

```py
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
```

but you don't really want to do it, it breaks everything and it should be used only when migrating really huge codebases.

Comment: This disables way more then only the eager execution